# Scripting open existing window instead of new window

Tags: arch-linux, i3

I'm trying to script a [dunst](https://github.com/dunst-project/dunst)/player interaction to dunstify playerctl metadata and open Spotify tracks by way of `spotify --uri=$(playerctl -p spotify metadata mpris:trackid`) when it's dismissed/clicked.

How can I make sure the existing Spotify window is opened rather than a brand new window?

If the answer requires very program-specific API knowledge, then please provide a practical approach to handling this problem. I'm specifically trying to solve this while using [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/).

I'm also curious about this in order to enhance how application launchers such as [rofi](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi) handle app-switching, to intervene with whether it should open a new window or an existing window (outside the context of `rofi -modi window` which handles intentional window switching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It was suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/emv57u/scripting_open_existing_window_instead_of_new/fdt5d5o) I use `dbus-send` to open Spotify from a URI, however I found limitations specific to the Spotify API (opening the URI restarted the track instead of *only* pulling up the artist page). This actually is a [Spotify bug](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Linux-Spotify-URI-only-opens-start-page/m-p/1675578#M1812).

Overall, the most appropriate strategy for a WM like i3 appears to be to check if the process is running and then conditionally focus the window or start the application as necessary. This is what I've settled on.

In i3, you can focus the window with `i3-msg '[class="Spotify"] focus'`. Use `xprop` to identify meta information in order to target a window.